# Jordanian Visa on Arrival for Indian citizens living in Germany

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, jordan

I am an Indian citizen planning to visit Jordan for 7 days. I have been living in Germany for 4 years on the EU Blue Card. I also have valid US, UK, and Canada visas.

I would like to know whether I am eligible for Visa on arrival?

The information on [Indian embassy website in Amman](https://indembassy-amman.gov.in/Visa_on_Arrival_in_Jordan.html) states:

> Indian nationals resident overseas are granted entry visa on arrival or through Jordan’s diplomatic Missions abroad.

P.S. I tried reaching the embassy in Berlin but did not receive a clear answer. They told me that my residency should be valid for 6 months. My Blue Card expires in May 2020 (same as my passport expiry date which I renewed recently) and I will be submitting my German PR application in February.

Answer (score 1):

Before 2018, you were in need of a visa in advance. I would suggest you reach Jordan Embassy of Germany if you want to verify. Phone number:+962 6 590 1170

However, in the mid-2018, Jordan tourism board has announced visa on arrival for Indians at all border crossings. The visa will be valid for a period of 30 days.

> A proof of the onward journey or a return ticket is the only
>   documents required for the procedure. However, the Indian travellers
>   can continue to get visas prior to their journey from the Jordanian
>   diplomatic missions in the country.

Other Asian countries that can acquire visa on arrival to Jordan are Andorra, Bahrain, Bhutan, Brunei, Burma, China, Taiwan, Hong Kong, Indonesia, Israel, Japan, Kazakhstan, Kuwait, Kyrgyzstan, Lebanon, Macau, Malaysia, Maldives, North Korea, Oman, Palestine, Qatar, Russia, Saudi Arabia, Singapore, South Korea, Syria, Tajikistan, Thailand, Turkey, Turkmenistan, United Arab Emirates, and Uzbekistan.

https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293986-i3134-k10571722-Jordanian_Visa_on_Arrival_for_Indian_Passport_Holders-Amman_Amman_Governorate.html

However, if you don't want to take a risk, you can apply prior to your journey from the Embassy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get a visa on arrival in Jordan. As per [the Jordan Embassy website](https://www.sticholidays.com/sticholidays/packages/visa-info.php?pkgID=842), Indian citizens do not require pre-approval.

As per this [site](https://www.sticholidays.com/sticholidays/packages/visa-info.php?pkgID=842), tourist visas can be for up to a 14 day's stay, and the fee is 60USD. You must bring:

- Hotel confirmation
- Confirmed return or onward tickets
- at least USD 1,000 in cash.
- a passport valid for at least 6 months beyond the intended stay in Jordan.
- A photocopy of the passport page containing the personal details and the address.
- One visa form (photocopy allowed).
- One passport-size photograph with white background.
- A cover letter from the Applicant stating the purpose of visit and duration of proposed stay.

Please note that for first-time travellers, travel agents aren't allowed: applicants must in-person apply for visas.

Comment: It's not the official Jordanian embassy website, It's STIC holidays. I cannot find the information on the official website. This website here http://international.visitjordan.com/page/4/VisasToJordan.aspx says "contact the embassy"